# Xcode has Sublime Text Icon

Tags: xcode, macos, icons, dock

I have no idea how it happened, if you go from `/Applications` the icon is correct, but once you put it on the dock it turns into the Sublime Text icon. Luckily it still opens Xcode correctly, but it's really annoying.

[image: Icon]

[image: Icon]

Comment: Try relaunching the finder with alt-right click on its dock icon?

Comment: Yeah, nothing changed.

Comment: It wants to be as good as Sublime Text

Answer (score 1):

It randomly fixed itself. Bah...

[image]